# Cant cache resource when having both gzip and Etag

Tags: http, caching, header, response

I am trying to cache a (javascript) resource in the browser and have properly set all of Cache-control:max-age, Expires, and Etag in the response headers (as is seen from the screenshot).

The browser requests with "if-none-match" and "if-modified-since", and in both cases the conditions are met:

- if-modified-since = last-modified (the file has never been changed)
- if-none-match = Etag (again, the files has never been changed)

So I should get response 304, right? But no, I keep getting 200 OK, which means that apache keeps serving the file (albeit compressed) every time. Tested with Firefox, Chrome, curl -- no use. Server always serves the whole file, even if I am not asking it to...

Using curl, I have traced the problem to **gzip & Etag**:

- if I remove the gzip (and cut the suffix -gzip from the request Etag) -- all is good: 304
- if I keep the gzip and remove the request Etag altogether -- all is good: 304
- but if I keep both 'accept-encoding:gzip' and the Etag, even though both request and response Etags are the same (this time with '-gzip' at the end), the server returns the wrong 200. It feels like apache compares the etag before gzipping the fail, decides it doesnt match, and then serves the file gzipped, even though after the gzip the Etag matches.

Here is the request/response:

- Request Method:  GET
- Status Code:     **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

**Request Headers 00:09:12.000**

- User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:36.0)
  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
- If-None-Match:   "24e55-51138062ce6c0-gzip"
- If-Modified-Since:   Sat, 14 Mar 2015 04:26:43 GMT
- Connection:  keep-alive
- Cache-Control:   max-age=0
- Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
- Accept:  */*

**Response Headers Δ1100ms**

- Vary:    Accept-Encoding
- Server:  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Last-Modified:   Sat, 14 Mar 2015 04:26:43 GMT
- Keep-Alive:  timeout=5, max=100
- Expires: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 16:09:13 GMT
- Etag:    "24e55-51138062ce6c0-gzip"
- Date:    Wed, 18 Mar 2015 16:09:13 GMT
- Content-Type:    application/javascript
- Content-Length:  53331
- Content-Encoding:    gzip
- Connection:  Keep-Alive
- Cache-Control:   max-age=604800

Comment: Would `Last-Modified` (without sending `ETag`) solve this issue? The problem with just removing the `-gzip` suffix I believe is that the uncompressed content (before GZIP) is the content being cached.

Answer (score 13):

Apache `mod_deflate` is creating unique Etag for each entity as these identify
the specific entity variant of the URL. Each negotiated variant needs to have unique ETag:s. For `mod_deflate` it's as simple as adding the encoding to the already computed ETag.

One workaround is to remove the encoding from the Etag:

```
<Location /js>
  RequestHeader  edit "If-None-Match" "^(.*)-gzip$" "$1"
  Header  edit "ETag" "^(.*[^g][^z][^i][^p])$" "$1-gzip"
</Location>
```

If you are using Apache 2.5 with the `mod_deflate` module, you can use the directive `DeflateAlterETag` to specifies how the ETag hader should be altered when a response is compressed.

```
DeflateAlterETag AddSuffix|NoChange|Remove
```

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatealteretag

This [blog post](https://fullstackhack.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/the-pain-of-etags-mod_deflate-apache-2-4-and-tomcat-7/) suggest to remove Etags altogether and to rely on the `Cache-Control` header.

To do that in `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None
```

Note that if entities gzip:ed by `mod_deflate` still carries the same ETag as the plain entiy, this may cause inconsistency in ETag aware proxy caches.

More info here:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023

Comment: For the first solution I removed the `Header edit` (as mod_deflate already adds it), and added `RequestHeader  edit "If-None-Match" "^(.*)-gzip\"$" "$1\""`(note the added double quotes at the end), as ETags are often quoted.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround not yet reported is, you can just apply this configuration:

```
RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" '^"((.*)-gzip)"$' '"$1", "$2"'
```

(Originally suggested by Joost Dekeijzer, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023#c22, and still working nowadays on version 2.4)

Answer (score 1):

There also seems to be a problem with gzipped resources like .js .css and the Vary: Accept-encoding Header with Chrome.

Please check my Anwser given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40726246/135785

This solved the problem for me:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
 # Serve correct encoding type.
 Header set Content-Encoding gzip
 # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
  BrowserMatch "Chrome" ChromeFound
 Header append Vary Accept-Encoding env=!ChromeFound
</FilesMatch>
```

Check your Apache Config for "Header append Vary Accept-Encoding"

Answer (score 1):

to modify the current top answer, the posted solution did not work for me (jan 2023) as apache was wrapping the ETag value in quotes, and was also looking for ETags without the `-gzip` suffix. after a bit of digging, i also found that there is an open bug in apache itself that is the root cause of this issue. (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39727)

here is a modified location block similar to the one above, but using the quotes, and removing the `-gzip` suffix on both outgoing and incoming requests. this is the solution that worked for me

```
<Location / >
    RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" '^"((.*)-gzip)"$' '"$1", "$2"'
    Header  edit "ETag"  '^"((.*)-gzip)"$' '"$2"'
</Location>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me too. I found I only needed the second part: `Header edit "ETag"  '^"(.*)-gzip"$' '"$1"'`.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should fix it

```
SetEnvIf If-None-Match '^"((.*)-(br))"$' br
SetEnvIf If-None-Match '^"((.*)-(gzip))"$' gzip

RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" '^"((.*)-(gzip|br))"$' '"$1"'

Header edit "ETag" '^"(.*)"$' '"$1-gzip"' env=gzip
Header edit "ETag" '^"(.*)"$' '"$1-br"' env=br
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the `Cache-Control: max-age=0` is at fault.

Quoting this post and its excellent answer: [What's the difference between Cache-Control: max-age=0 and no-cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache)

> On the other hand, sending a request with Cache-Control: no-cache (aka. "end-to-end reload") doesn't revalidate and the server MUST NOT use a cached copy when responding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately the issue is not due to max-age=0 in the *request* header. Here is another request, this time to google's hosted jquery library, where google gives me the correct 304 response. Dont confuse max-age=0 in the request with max-age=0 in the response (which would indeed mean "revalidate"). Also, the issue is not with caching on the server side but with caching on the client (browser) side

Comment: I am specifically referring to the headers sent from the client (check the quote in the answer), and your issue seems to be caching on the server side, since it's the server that does not return a 304 to you.
The Google example is clear though. One other option is that you have parameters in your URL - see the list here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

Comment: No, no parameters... Actually this is the url: http://www.sgxderivatives.com/assets/js/d3.min.js